Remove public IPv4 from AWS EC2 instances
Since February 1, 2024, AWS started charging for public IPv4 and I have several EC2 instances.
Some instances I can having only public IPv6, for others I need to keep public IPv4. I disabled Elastic IP and type A addresses for one instance for testing. However, when I remove public IPv4 from an instance, it stops accessing IPv4 internet. IPv6 internet works fine, and it still keeps a private IPv4.
From what I understand, I should create a NAT gateway, but I don't see how I can do this without changing the instance's VPC or subnet and for that I need to terminate the instance and create another one, which complicates the process too much.
What is the step-by-step procedure to disable public IPv4 on an instance without breaking anything? What am I missing?

This method works to remove a public IP, I've tried it myself. I've added a copy / my own notes on how to do it below in case the link changes.
A NAT gateway allows an instance with only a private IPv4 address to reach the IPv4 internet. Of course a NAT gateway costs significantly more than an IPv4 address, so it only makes sense if you have 3 or 4 instances. You don't need to change anything about your instance to use a NAT gateway, you simply deploy your NAT gateway to a public subnet and route internet traffic to it. There are many tutorials, this one looks like it should work.

Go to your running EC2 instance with the public IP you want to remove. Note what region and availability zone are associated with that instance.
On the left-hand panel, scroll and go into “Network Interfaces” under the “Network and Security” Dropdown. Once there, click “Create Network Interface.” In the description, give it a memorable name (we used “TEST 1b” in this example). For the subnet, pick a matching one for the instance from Step 1. Click “Create” to finish.
Next, go it elastic IPs (also under the “Network and Security” Dropdown). After you create a new elastic IP, associate it with the EC2 instance.
Next, go back to your running EC2. Right-click it and select “Attach Network Interface” under the “Networking” option
From here, attach the network interface made previously.
Next, disassociate the elastic IP from the instance. If done properly, the public IP should disappear.
Release elastic IP address
Remove network interface from instance

